# My diamond cup wheel keeps spinning off when slowing down

Tags: concrete, basement, tile, thinset

I've run into a problem, I need to to remove some very stubborn thinset in my basement bathroom and also level some uneven concrete.

I decided to try out the angle grinder method, I have a Bosch 1375A 4.5" angle grinder, Ridgid 5" diamond cup wheel and a Herzo 4-5" universal dust shroud.  My problem is the wheel spins off when the grinder is slowing down, I'm assuming it must have a brake, so the wheel doesn't slow down as fast as the grinder and so it spins itself off.  Has anyone encountered this problem?

Any suggestions on what I should do or suggestions on an angle grinder that would work properly with the wheel and shroud that I have?

Comment: Have you cranked down tight on the nut holding the wheel in place? No, tighter than that! Alternatively, have a scrap block of wood nearby that you can dig the wheel into as you release the trigger - that should slow the whole thing right down.

Comment: Are you using a wrench to tighten it on? On my diamond cup wheel it has flat spots on the sides of the shaft that you put a wrench on to tighten it on.  You have to use the locking mechanism  on the grinder.

Comment: i had a harbor fright one that was helped with some electrical tape getting smooshed between the disc and collar/nut to keep things tight and frictiony. You could also hot glue it in place, then use a lighter to remove it later.

Comment: It really sounds like you're not tightening things properly. I recently watched a video where a person demonstrates various angle grinder wheels and he only installed them by hand-tightening the nut and then showing the disc in action. I really hope you didn't learn from that video as I would imagine he tightened it properly off screen.

Comment: I tried with the locknut on, tightened pretty good I thought, problem was the wheel rubbed against the dust shroud and the wheel and lock nut both spun off on slow down.. with the backing flange on there's no room for the lock nut, so I also tried putting spacer washers in place of the backing flange and put the lock nut on, still everything came off.  I haven't tried tightening it with a wrench, no room to get the wrench in there with the dust shroud on though.  Could try wrapping electrical tape around the spindle or using a block of wood too, I'd just like to get it to work properly.

Comment: usually I just wrap a rag around the wheel (or put on a leather glove)  and tighten the wheel by hand as tight as it will go. (I don't know how many torques that is) but my grinder doesn't have a brake.

Comment: Keep your wheel in contact with the surface when you release the switch. I have seen guys use a small piece of paper in the threads and last There are temporary thread lockers that are a gel , they don’t get as hard as lock tight thread locker. As I mentioned first I just keep my grinder in contact with the work if a brushed motor it will last longer than depending on the brake.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I gave it a go with the spacer washers and no locknut, tightened as best I could, I just held it close to the floor when I shut it off case the wheel came off, it came off a few times, but I think with the pressure on the wheel from the grinding might actually tighten it a little too.